# cronjob config for run an url who have an automatic click button script

Tags: javascript, cron

I have a question for you, actually give me some advice on how to make a button press automatically from a php script twice a day, without entering that page. For example, if I enter the page manually, it is clicked automatically, I have this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
setInterval(function() {
      // form button click on every second
      document.getElementById('save_ical').click();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

In order for the page to run without entering it manually, I configured a cronjob:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null "myurlishere" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Twice Per Hour
(0,30 * * * *)

But what I did seems not to work. Any sugestion?

Comment: this won't work.  There are tools that simulate web browsers (mostly for testing) like Selenium.  The real question is why you are trying to make this so complex;  Writing a PHP script to do a server process from a web browser that is triggered by running a fake browser connection from the same server seems like it's needlessly complex.

Comment: thank you for your answer. any sugestion to submit that button whitout window.load?

Answer (score 0):

`wget` only gets response from a web-server. It does not run JavaScript code and not even parse the HTML, like if it's just a bunch of text.

In your case, you probably don't need to click button. Instead, you should do the same as the browser does after the button has clicked. For example, if it is a form submit button, just make the same http-request as browser made after submitting the form.

Comment: thank you for your answer. that button sincronize rezervation from arbnb to our platform, and most of our clients do not enter to sincronize. that i need to sincronize the information automation.